# How can I execute remaining batch script commands after calling exit?

Tags: batch-file

I have these two lines in my batch script:

```
call pre.bat
call post.bat
```

And I have a exit condition in `pre.bat` (i.e. `exit 255`)

How can I execute `post.bat` even if `pre.bat` exits with an error code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `exit /b 255` instead of `exit 255` in your pre.bat

If you cannot change pre.bat, then you can use `start /b /wait pre.bat` instead of `call pre.bat`. But then all changes to environment variables that pre.bat might have made will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to achieve this without changing `pre.bat`?